# In Pandas, how can I group by every N rows within a key, saving the last value of one column and calculating another based on all rows in that 'set'?

Tags: python, pandas

I have data that is structured like below with a time, category, active indicator and a numerical value.

**Input**

```
i  time       cat.  active  item_count
0  00:00:00   X     TRUE    2
1  00:00:06   X     FALSE   4
2  00:00:08   X     TRUE    13
3  00:00:25   Y     FALSE   11
4  00:01:10   Y     TRUE    2
5  00:01:58   Y     TRUE    6
6  00:02:53   Y     TRUE    2
7  07:40:29   X     FALSE   1
8  08:34:52   X     FALSE   2
9  11:50:48   X     TRUE    5
10 11:55:42   X     TRUE    3
```

I want to calculate the rate of active items for every 2 rows within a category, and copy the time of the last row in each 2-row set to get this output:

**Output**

```
time     cat.  rate
00:00:06 X     0.33 (2/(2+4))
07:40:29 X     13/14
00:01:10 Y     2/13
00:02:53 Y     8/8
11:50:48 X     5/7
11:55:42 X     3/3
```

The 'sets' in the input would be the rows [[0,1], [2,7], [8,9], [10]] for category X and [[3,4],[5,6]] for category Y.

How would I set this up? Sort by category, then time, then step through every N items? I found GroupBy.nth while searching for a solution though am not sure if it applies here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First create helper `Series` with [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), pass to another `groupby` and aggregate lambda function with `last`, last some data cleaning - [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `rename`:

Also for `rate` column need sum only `True` values and divide from right side by [`rdiv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rdiv.html) with `sum` of all values.

```
g = df.groupby('cat.').cumcount() // 2
df1 = (df.groupby(['cat.', g], sort=False)
        .agg({'item_count': 'sum', 'time':'last'}))

print (df1)
        item_count      time
cat.                        
X    0           6  00:00:06
     1          14  07:40:29
Y    0          13  00:01:10
     1           8  00:02:53
X    2           7  11:50:48
     3           3  11:55:42

s = df[df['active']].groupby(['cat.', g], sort=False)['item_count'].sum()
print (s)
cat.   
X     0     2
      1    13
Y     0     2
      1     8
X     2     5
      3     3
Name: item_count, dtype: int64
```

---

```
df1['rate'] = df1.pop('item_count').rdiv(s, axis=0)

d= {'time_last':'time'}
df1 = df1.reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index().rename(columns=d)
print (df1)
  cat.      time      rate
0    X  00:00:06  0.333333
1    X  07:40:29  0.928571
2    Y  00:01:10  0.153846
3    Y  00:02:53  1.000000
4    X  11:50:48  0.714286
5    X  11:55:42  1.000000
```

Comment: It seems there are some issues with `00:02:53` and `00:01:10` outputs, no ?

Comment: @RobinFrcd - Now  understand.

Comment: @RobinFrcd - thank you for comment, answer was edited.

Comment: Wow, you are fast. Thank you for your very thorough answer and follow-up edit!

Comment: @RobHawkins - Thank you for nice question, only there should by more clarify need divide sum of `True`s values. Btw, if no `True` for group, get `NaN`s in output, it is OK ?

Comment: @jezrael Good question. In that case I would just dropna() right?

Comment: @RobHawkins - Yes, or replace by `0` by `fillna(0)`, it depends what need.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it, I'm not really using tools that pandas provides but it's a (seemingly) working solution until one using pandas tools comes out.

```py
def rate_dataframe(df):
    df_sorted = df.sort_values(['cat.', 'time', 'active'])

    prev_row = df_sorted.iloc[0]
    cat_count, active_count, not_active_count = 0, 0, 0

    ratio_rows = list()

    for _, row in df_sorted.iterrows():
        if row['active']:
            active_count += row['item_count']
        else:
            not_active_count += row['item_count']

        if cat_count == 1 and prev_row['cat.'] == row['cat.']:
            ratio = active_count / (active_count + not_active_count)
            ratio_rows.append([row['time'], row['cat.'], ratio]) 
            cat_count, active_count, not_active_count = 0, 0, 0

        elif cat_count == 0:
            cat_count += 1

        elif cat_count == 1 and prev_row['cat.'] != row['cat.']:
            # handle last row in cat if nbCatRows is odd
            if row['active']:
                active_count, not_active_count = row['item_count'], 0
            else:
                active_count, not_active_count = 0, row['item_count']
            ratio_rows.append([
                prev_row['time'], 
                prev_row['cat.'], 
                int(prev_row['active'])
            ])  

        prev_row = row

    return pd.DataFrame(ratio_rows, columns=['time', 'cat.', 'rate'])
```

[image: rate output]

Comment: Hi Robin, thank you for taking the time to answer. I'm going to compare the two answers given and make sure I know how all this works so I can make better use of Pandas in the future.